# Is it possible to run Apache and IIS on the same machine with one IP-Address (and different ports ?)

Tags: django, apache, iis-6

The "main" one should be IIS. Is there an option to address the Apache without typing in the port-number
The reason for this is: I cannot get Django to work on IIS
Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need IIS? have some MS tech?

Answer (score 5):

You could set up Apache on a different port, then use redirects or proxying on IIS to get people to the Apache port without them having to type it.

Comment: I thought reverse proxy on IIS was only available on ISA server?  Please correct me if i'm wrong.  In any case apache can also be used as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to avoid typing in the port number is to set up a proxy, which could be either one of the two webservers. That way, the proxy makes the connection on the alternate port and the client doesn't have to know where it is.

I don't know about IIS, but on Apache, you would have to load mod_proxy (and I think, mod_proxy_http) and then do something like this:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Also check [the docs for mod_proxy online](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html).

You might also want to look at lightweight webservers such as [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), if you're going to have two running. It's a common setup to have a light webserver taking specific tasks away from the main one. (Apache for dynamic and lighttpd for static content is one typical example).

There's also other possibilities, ranging from getting more fancy, such as

- Have a third webserver doing only the proxying and the other two on alternate ports
- Have them running on the same port but two IPs and hide that fact via your network setup

to attacking the root cause by either

- finding somenone who knows how to get Django running on IIS
- moving from IIS to another webserver

Of course, I have no clue what might be appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a matter of running Django on a server that already needs IIS, you can run django on IIS directly, thanks to efforts like [Django-IIS](http://code.google.com/p/django-iis/) and [PyISAPIe](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer). I think it would be preferable to NOT run a second web server when all its going to be doing is proxying requests out to a third server, the Django code.